# Awk , but print only a portion of a field

Tags: linux, bash, printing, awk

I am concerned with only a portion of a particular field (hostname) in a log line and would like to print all the unique occurrences of said portion. I am currently doing something like:

```
    zcat $file | awk '$2~/f/ {print $14}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

The problem is field 14 will be really long and contain a bunch of stuff like

```
/=/%%/25284687/hostname/auhga/giu/2985729/%/etc...
```

Hostnames may vary and I want to print only the uniqe hostnames, sort them and count them, etc. How can I better structure my awk command to achieve this? Important to note everything prepending and appending the /hostname/ portion varies.

Comment: Will the hostname always be 5th slash-delimited field of $14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hostnames are always between the 4th and the 5th `/` in the `awk` output, then this process will extract them:

```
cut -d / -f 5
```

Place it just after your original `awk`.